# mysql rand() alternative [has to meet certain criteria]

Tags: mysql, random

My current query looks like that

```
SELECT *
FROM uploads
WHERE approved = 1
    AND (up-down) >= 3
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 10
```

This is to select random 10 entries from DB which have atleast 3 likes more than dislikes.

The problem is because I have over 40k entries in DB and this query takes alteast 1 second.

I read a lot on google but didn't find anything so far.

Is there any alternative you would recommend in my case?

Comment: Do you have indexes on columns?

Comment: How many rows match the WHERE criteria? How long does the query take if you don't use `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Is it possible for you to alter the schema?

Comment: Yes I do have indexes.24k out of 42k rows match where criteria.If I dont use order by it takes about half a second(entries are always same).I would prefer not to change the chema, but will do if needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're loading all matching records into memory, and if there aren't too many of them, then the simplest answer is just to drop the `order by` in your SQL, and sort them randomly in your application software. eg if you're using PHP, you could simply load them all into an array, and then call `array_rand()`.

If this isn't a suitable answer, then and you still need to sort them in the DB, then in cases where `order by rand()` is too slow (ie most cases where you have a large amount of data), the best solution I know of is as follows:

Add a new column to your table, and pre-populate it with an MD5 hash of the primary key for each record. And add an index to sort by the new field.

This will give you an evenly-distributed random sort order for the table. Simply `order by` this field instead of `rand()`.

Comment: If he uses an MD5 hash and sorts by that, that will give the same 10 elements each time he queries. Not very random.

Comment: Yeah first answer is not suitable because 24k records match and wouldn't be smart to load this in memory every request user makes.

But I dont understand what you mean by hashing primary key.My primary key is field ID which auto increments every upload.

Comment: by 'hashing by the primary key', I'm simply assuming the primary key is a unique value per record. Therefore it will give a unique hash value per record. The actual value is irrelevant -- it doesn't have to be the primary key, it could be any other value that's unique for each record; the important point is that MD5 hashed values provide a good random order, provided you use a unique value for each hash.

Comment: @Barmar - this is true, but there are ways to mitigate it. For example, re-populate the hashes for records that you've queried. But the real point is that it's a solution to the speed problem. Ultimately, if you need a fast query, you need to query on an index, and if you need a fast random query, you need to query on a randomly sorted index. The question is how important is performance?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach depends on a number of factors.  Here are some ideas.

Assuming there are no indices, the current version of the query is doing a full table scan, extracting the rows, assigning a random number, sorting the rows, and then choosing the first 10 of these.

The full table scan might be slow the first time, but should be quite fast after that, assuming that the table fits in memory.  Let me assume that your performance issue does not refer to the first instance of the query, but to one where the table is already in the page cache.

If "approved" is highly selective -- say, 1% of the rows are approved -- then you might be able to speed up the query by building an index on approved.

The next alternative is to add a column for "up - down" and build an index on the two keys, approved and UpMinusDown.  Assuming this is selective, it can reduce the speed.

The next question is if you could replace the `rand()` with some other criteria -- the 10 most recent, for instance.  If so, you could include a primary key say UploadID and use that for the sort.  It would go faster.

Finally, if your records are very wide, it could be the sort that it taking up the time.  In this case, I wonder if the following version of the query would perform better:

```
SELECT *
FROM uploads u left outer join
     (select UploadID
      from uploads
      WHERE approved = 1
            AND (up-down) >= 3
     ORDER BY RAND()
     LIMIT 10
    ) random
    on u.UploadID = random.UploadID
```

(This assumes that you have a primary key on the table called UploadID.)

This version should do the sort only on the UpLoadID and then join it back to the original data using an index.

Comment: I have indicies made on all columns mentioned above.There is also column 'id' which is primary index(auto increment).

Most of the uploads are approved(95%+).Yeah I know showing 10 most recent records is the way but I need random function too.